# Unable to require redis in ruby

Tags: ruby, redis

I'm not able to require redis although clearly it is installed? What else can I try?

```
$ sudo gem install redis
  Fetching: redis-3.0.7.gem (100%)
  Successfully installed redis-3.0.7
  Parsing documentation for redis-3.0.7
  Installing ri documentation for redis-3.0.7
  Done installing documentation for redis after 0 seconds
  1 gem installed
$ ./test.rb 
  /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such   file -- redis (LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from ./test.rb:9:in `<main>'
```

My code:

```
#test.rb
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'redis'
```

Answer (score -1):

It is likely an issue involving having two (or more) Ruby installations on your machine.

Try comparing the RUBY VERSION line you get when you run `gem environment` and the result of `ruby --version`

Comment: Also, the issue could be related to installing the gem using `sudo`